# Free memory in a function

Tags: c

Which it is the correct way to release the memory in this case; there is some difference between the two methods?

```
void allocateArray1(int size, int value)
{
    int* arr = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
    /* ... */
    free(arr);
}

int* allocateArray2(int size, int value)
{
    int* arr = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
    /* ... */
    return arr;
}

int main()
{
    int* vector = allocateArray2(5,45);
    free(vector);
    allocateArray1(5,45);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Obviously there is a difference. In `allocateArray1()`, your `main()` function never sees or knows about the array, and so cannot do anything with it. Use this method when that's exactly what you want `main()` to be not able to do.

Comment: Note that `malloc` and `free` *do not care* how *your* functions work. All they care about is that memory allocated with `malloc` is eventually freed with `free`.

Comment: it doesn't matter which one you choose, if `main` doesn't have any business messing with that memory you've allocated, just allocate and free within the scope of the called function.

Comment: As you work more with dynamically allocated memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) always *preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed. How you do that is up to you as long as you take care of both. *You* are the memory  manager in C for the memory you allocate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are equivalent, because both allocation with `malloc` and release with `free`.  The `allocateArray1` method does it all in one function, which makes it easier to remember to free the memory.  But sometimes you need the function to provide main (or some other function) with memory, so it can use it.  In that case you'll just have to delete it later, as in the `allocateArray2` method.

Answer (score 1):

This is sometimes what's known as “ownership semantics”, i.e. who *owns* the object (and therefore who is responsible for freeing the object).

Some functions require the caller to free the returned object, e.g. [`strdup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strdup.html), or sometimes the POSIX [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getdelim.html) function too. In these cases, the `strdup()` and `getline()` functions can't know what you plan to do with the result or how long you'll need the result for, so they delegate the task of freeing the object to the caller of the function.

Other library functions may return an object whose lifetime is already maintained by the library itself, so there is no need to free anything.

It's important when developing a project to have consistent ownership semantics. For example, perhaps any function that delegates the task of freeing objects could start with `alloc` (or `new` or `create` etc.), and then you'll always know that freeing the result of these functions is your responsibility. It's not really important how the ownership semantics are defined, as long as they are consistent.

Answer (score 0):

> Which it is the correct way to release the memory in this case; there is some difference between the two methods?

Both methods are correct.

However, i will prefer to use `int* allocateArray2(int size, int value)` function which allocates some memory from the heap inside the function and return pointer to allocated memory space. 
The primary reason malloc is needed is when you have data that must have a lifetime that is different from code scope. Your code calls malloc in one routine, stores the pointer somewhere and eventually calls free in a different routine.

`void allocateArray1(int size, int value)` function which asks for some memory, does some processing and frees the memory before returning is not the efficient method if the `size` is less. You can instead create the array on the stack and use it for further processing. The advantage of using the stack to store variables, is that memory is managed for you. You don't have to allocate memory by hand, or free it once you don't need it any more. What's more, because the CPU organizes stack memory so efficiently, reading from and writing to stack variables is very fast. However, it may cause stack overflow, if you attempt to allocate more memory on the stack than will fit, for example by creating local array variables that are too large.

An example of a very large stack variable in C:

```
int foo() 
{
     double x[1048576];
}
```

The declared array consumes 8 mebibytes of data (assuming each double is 8 bytes); if this is more memory than is available on the stack (as set by thread creation parameters or operating system limits), a stack overflow will occur.